# Thread 1 received signal SIGABART error

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

Im getting the following error when hitting the email button in my application on the simulator.  Im using the same code form a previous application so the code must be ok

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

Im having trouble interpreting what this means, the debugger says

```
argc = (int)1
argv = (char**) 0Xbffff594
*argv = char 0xbffff6b8/users/library/apllications/5.1/applications/FBA888AA-xxxxxx

In thread 1

0x0028b626  <+1163>  xor    %eax,%eax
0x951929c6  <+0010>  jae    0x951929d6 <__pthread_kill+26>
```

I have rebooted machine, still same error

Could anyone offer any advice?

Comment: Try to narrow down where the actual error is being generated.  Use the breakpoint inspector to break when exceptions are thrown and see if that gives you a view of the stack at the point the problem is generated.  Failing that, try catching the exception and logging it and the associated stack symbols.

Comment: add an exception breakpoint as in this article and try to find a more specific line http://ijoshsmith.com/2011/11/28/debugging-exceptions-in-xcode-4-2/

Comment: Even if you pulled the code from another, functioning app, we need to see the relevant portions of the code to help you diagnose your problem.

Comment: TThanks for the replies, im getting this in the debugger: `2012-04-03 16:53:30.388 CableCalc[4206:15e03] -[FirstViewController email:]: unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x7f861d0
2012-04-03 16:53:30.389 CableCalc[4206:15e03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FirstViewController email:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f861d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1387022 0x193fcd6 0x1388cbd 0x12eded0 0x12edcb2 0x1388e99 0x28e14e 
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)`

Comment: my code: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
if ( [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] ) {
MFMailComposeViewController * mailComposer = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] self];
 mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailComposer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"attachment.jpg"];`

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your App-delegate in .h file`@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;`

and this line to your App-delegate .m file `@synthesize viewController = _viewController;`

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your App-delegate in .h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;
```

and this line to your App-delegate .m file

```
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;
```

Comment: I've copied what Saif had posted but replaced `ViewController` to `UIViewController` for the App-delegate .h file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have a connection broken. You should double check all your connections in Interface Builder.

Re-connect your connection or delete the connection.